# How to disable right click on lightbox images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal-6, lightbox

I'm using Drupal6 lightbox2 module
Already i disabled right click on images in my site.
But my client asking me to disable right click in the lightbox images too. 
And he told me that not to watermark the images.
I tried by adding the script to lightbox js file but it doesn't works.

I added oncontextmenu="return false" to the image tag in lightbox js file but 
it disabled the right click throughout the site.

So could anyone help me in this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Always post your code =)
It's easier to help you if you post your code.

Comment: @Alex.I'm using this script in my page.tpl file.

Comment: @Alex.I'm using this script in my page.tpl file.<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
 function right(e) {
  var msg = "Right Click is disabled!";
  if (navigator.appName == 'Netscape' && e.which == 3) {
  alert(msg);
  return false;
  }
  if (e == null){ //IE disable
         e = window.event;
        if (e.button==2) {
         alert(msg);
         return false;
          }
         }
  else return true;
  }
 
 function trap(){
  if(document.images){ 
   for(i=0;i<document.images.length;i++){
    document.images[i].onmousedown = right;
    document.images[i].onmouseup = right;
   }
  }
 }
</SCRIPT>

Comment: and in the body tag I included this one.<body onLoad="trap();">.This is what worked for images in my site and not worked for lightbox images.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, I know you don't like that answer, but you need to educate your client instead of just doing such things. Tell him that it's more important to give the user a good experience than psudo-securing the images. Also, there really *is no way* you can prevent users from saving images from a web page. And that's the way it's supposed to be.

Comment: @Rudolph .I already told my client but he just want to disable right click on lightbox images..will try one more time too.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that all images have a specific class, you could do something like this:

```
$('.lightbox_images').bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
    return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2GmLf/

**EDIT**
Take a look at this example using [Colorbox](http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/).
I used Firebug to identify the class that the plugin applies in images which in this case is `cboxPhoto`.

Also changed the [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) to [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

http://jsfiddle.net/2GmLf/2/

Comment: @Alex.My lightbox image div id is lightboxImage.Hence i used this code in lightbox js file.the right click is not disabled.

$('#lightboxImage').bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
    return false;
});

Comment: @Alex.When i used this code the images are not showing in lightbox istead it is opening in a nes tab..Am idoing anything wrong????$('#lightboxImage').live("contextmenu", function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    return false;
});

Comment: Ok. What's the lightbox plugin are you using? Where's the code of the lightbox? (edit your question, do not post it at the comments).

Answer (score 1):

```
(function($){
    $(document).on('contextmenu', 'img', function() {
        return false;
    })
})(jQuery);
```

when light box popup open this disables the right click on images

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 $('img').live("contextmenu",function(e){
    return false;
});
```

Here's a working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/NRW2H/ ;

Comment: @Frank.But it doesn't works.Yes,the images are loaded dynamically.

Comment: @Frank.Using this code in lightbox module js file,leads to open the image in new tab instead of showing in lightbox. $('img').live("contextmenu",function(e){
    return false;
});

Answer (score 0):

try this...

Add this attribute in your img tag inner lightbox.
    oncontextmenu="return false"

Like this:

```
<div> // lightbox container
// others div's
<img src="..." "alt="..." oncontextmenu="return false" >
```

I hope helps for you need

Best regards.